# Why `\\` is wrong here?

Tags: line-breaking, brackets, syntax

The following codes return errors

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
cd\\
[asd]
\end{document}
```

But this one will work

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
cd

[asd]
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: This is caused by `[` I think. `\\ ` can take an optional argument, which is a length. LaTeX picks up `[asd]` as an optional argument to `\\ `, but `asd` is not a valid length, so you get an error. There have been similar questions before I think.

Comment: Instead use `cd\\\relax
[asd]`.  The `\relax` will prevent the following bracket from being taken as an argument.